# ROR + Migration command gives strange error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, migration

```
Facing a strange problem while running migration command for creating one column.
```

[image]

```
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:777:in `block in activate_dependencies'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:766:in `each'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:766:in `activate_dependencies'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:750:in `activate'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:780:in `block in activate_dependencies'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:766:in `each'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:766:in `activate_dependencies'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:750:in `activate'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:212:in `rescue in try_activate'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:209:in `try_activate'
```

Not able to configure why such error is coming at console.

Answer (score 0):

After a long struggle on Google, I got the solution to solve my problem.

added bundle exec to my migration command

```
bundle exec rails generate migration AddStatusToUser status:boolean
```

As I found some of issue occurred due to conflicts in Gems.